# How to stop Gmail app checking emails in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, gmail

Is it possible to stop Gmail iOS app checking email without me asking for it? 
I don't need the phone to check for emails while I'm in from of my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the GMail app is a third party app not built by Apple, it is not allowed to run in the background to check for mails. So closing the app stops it from checking for mails.
However, it probably will still get notifications about new mails pushed from Google's server. But this notification is not initiated from your phone.

You can switch off notifications for the gmail app in the iPhones settings.app under notifications.

Comment: Thanks, turned notifications for gmail app Off, waiting for mail to check if it worked.

Comment: I have turned off everything there, except for badge and sound. Ant it seems the app still receives some notifications about emails.

Comment: Whith everything off it seems gmail stopped checking my email :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The answer was correct in 2013, when I wrote it. On newer versions of iOS you may also need to disable `Background App Refresh`.